# Display services under shipping method

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to display services under shipping method (either existing or custom shipping method also fine) in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, i used free shipping method, under collect rates i copied existing method code and replicated the same for more methods

find the code change below.

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

    $this->_updateFreeMethodQuote($request);

    if ($request->getFreeShipping() || $request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >= $this->getConfigData(
        'free_shipping_subtotal'
    )
    ) {

        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier('freeshipping');
        $method->setCarrierTitle('In-Store Pickup');

        $method->setMethod('Store1');
        $method->setMethodTitle('Store1');

        $method->setPrice('0.00');
        $method->setCost('0.00');

        $result->append($method);

        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier('freeshipping');
        $method->setCarrierTitle('In-Store Pickup');

        $method->setMethod('Store2');
        $method->setMethodTitle('Store2');

        $method->setPrice('0.00');
        $method->setCost('0.00');

        $result->append($method);




    }

    return $result;
}
```

the outcome will be look like in the image

[image]